# Why does memmove behave different when i want to replace a string at the first letter?

Tags: c, string, memmove

In the Code below, i don't understand, why i have to write memmove like this in the if statement when pos == 0 (when i want to replace at the first position of the string array) : 

**strlen(string1) - strlen(string2+1))**

I think i don't understand how many bytes i have to choose for my memmove function.

What is the different between the if and the else statement?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void cleanup(char *string1, char *string2, int pos);
int indexe(char string1[], char string2[]);

int main() {
    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];

    printf("PUT YOUR STRING\n");
    scanf("%99s", string1);

    printf("WHICH LETTERS DELETE?\n");
    scanf("%99s", string2);

    printf("String1 vorher: %s\n", string1);


    while(strstr(string1, string2)){
            cleanup(string1, string2,indexe(string1, string2));
    }

    printf("String1 before: %s\n", string1);
    printf("String1 after: %d\n", strlen(string1));

    return 0;
}

void cleanup(char *string1, char *string2, int pos) {

    pos = pos - strlen(string2);


    if(pos == 0){
    memmove(&string1[pos], &string1[pos + strlen(string2)], strlen(string1) - strlen(string2+1));
    }
    else
    memmove(&string1[pos], &string1[pos + strlen(string2)], strlen(string1) - strlen(string2));

}


int indexe(char string1[], char string2[]){

    char *firstpos = string1;
    char *secondpos = strstr(string1, string2);



    int pos = secondpos - firstpos + strlen(string2);

    printf("deleted index: %d\n", pos);

    return pos;

}
```

output: dayhousedayhouse

NOTE: the code does what i want. I only want to understand why :)

Comment: `strlen(string2+1)` is more or less equivalent to `strlen(string2) - 1`. Does it help?

Comment: Not if `string2` is the empty string. It's a dangerous practice.

Comment: @rodrigo i know, but why do i have to behave different when i want to replace to first character of the string. why do i have to write strlen(string2+1) when pos == 0 but strlen(string2) when pos != 0 ?

Comment: @Sedem.: Well you want to remove each occurence of 2nd string from 1st isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the target and source and then saying how many bytes to move.

```
holidayhousedayhouse0
^   ^
```

These are `target` and the `source` positions. Now how many bytes to move? You said

```
strlen(string1) - strlen(string2+1)
```

which is same as

```
20 - 3 = 17
```

That much byte is moved precisely. (The `\0` is copied too).

```
holidayhousedayhouse0
^   ^
dayhousedayhouse0
^   
|---------------|
     17 chars
```

---

`string2+1` - `string2` points to the beginning of the array - which is th first character in the array (`h`) here. When you add `1` - it basically moves by the size to which it points to - size of `char` is `1` so it moves by `1` position. That's why you get the length of `3` as if you counted letters from the second letter `o`. (upto `\0`).

---

The explanation provided above hints that the `cleanup` logic can be done simply using the `if` part's `memcpy` statement. The `else` part can be omitted.

The code you have shown is overcomplicating things given the simple task. The removal logic can be uniform. [***This***](https://ideone.com/0kNkOO) works.

Comment: when i have the array holidayhousedayhouse and i want to replace the word "seda", then i use the other if case with <b>strlen(string1) - strlen(string2)</b> and then i have to calculate 20-4 = 16 (NOT 20 -3 = 17) but my string has 17 chars at the end like in your example. because the word "seda" has 4 letters like "holi"

Comment: yes. but why is it different when i do these two things [1] remove stringpart from somewhere in string1 [2] remove stringpart from beginning in string1. i dont understand because in both cases i only delete 4 letters, so that my string has 16 letters at the end. but why do i have to do [1] 20-4 and [2] 20-3

Comment: @Sedem.: Check the code. The else is not needed here.

Comment: i wanted to shorten my code. i edit the code so that you can see the whole correct code

Comment: @Sedem.: Have you checke dthe code I have shown? I also mentioned that `else` can be omitted here.